# How to check node LTS version of Node in terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

I'm curious—is there a way to check the latest LTS version of Node.js from the terminal?

For the Node.js version, I'm aware that I can run the command

> node --version

to check the current version. Additionally, it's quite convenient to use nvm (Node Version Manager) to target different versions and switch between them effortlessly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```bash
nvm ls-remote --lts
```

This command lists all the LTS versions available through Node Version Manager (nvm). It will display a list of LTS versions, and the one at the top is the latest LTS version.